# Framerate dropping when drawing multiple textures in OpenGL ES iOS

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, drawing

Basically what I'm doing is making a simple finger drawing application. I have a single class that takes the input touch points and does all the fun work of turning those touch points into bezier curves, calculating vertices from those, etc. That's all working fine.

The only interesting constraint I'm working with is that I need strokes to blend on on top of each other, but not with themselves. Imagine having a scribbly line that crosses itself and has 50% opacity. Where the line crosses itself, there should be no visible blending (it should all look like the same color). However, the line SHOULD blend with the rest of the drawing below it.

To accomplish this, I'm using two textures. A back texture and a scratch texture. While the line is actively being updated (during the course of the stroke), I disable blending, draw the vertices on the scratch texture, then enable blending, and draw the back texture and scratch texture into my frame buffer. When the stroke is finished, I draw the scratch texture into the back texture, and we're ready to start the next stroke.

This all works very smoothly on a newer device, but on older devices the frame rate takes a severe hit. From some testing, it seems that the biggest performance hit is in drawing the textures to the frame buffer, because they're relatively large textures (due to the iPhone's retina resolution).
Does anybody have any hints on some strategies to work around this? I'm happy to provide more specifics or code, I'm just not sure where to start.

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0, targeting iOS 7.0, but testing on an iPhone 4S

The following is code I'm using to draw into the framebuffers:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self drawRect:rect
         ofTexture:_backTex
       withOpacity:1.0];

    if (_activeSpriteStroke)
    {
        [self drawStroke:_activeSpriteStroke
         intoFrameBuffer:0];
    }
}
```

Those rely on the following few methods:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
       ofTexture:(GLuint)tex
     withOpacity:(CGFloat)opacity
{
    _texShader.color = GLKVector4Make(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, opacity);

    [_texShader prepareToDraw];

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_texVertexVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _texVertexVBO);

    [self bufferTexCoordsForRect:rect];

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
}

- (void)drawStroke:(AHSpriteStroke *)stroke
   intoFrameBuffer:(GLuint)frameBuffer
{
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    [self renderStroke:stroke
           ontoTexture:_scratchTex
         inFrameBuffer:_scratchFrameBuffer];

    if (frameBuffer == 0)
    {
        [self bindDrawable];
    }
    else
    {
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    }

    [self setScissorRect:_activeSpriteStroke.boundingRect];
    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    [self drawRect:self.bounds
         ofTexture:_scratchTex
       withOpacity:stroke.lineOpacity];

    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}

- (void)renderStroke:(AHSpriteStroke *)stroke
         ontoTexture:(GLuint)tex
       inFrameBuffer:(GLuint)framebuffer
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _msFrameBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [stroke render];

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, _msFrameBuffer);
    glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE();

    const GLenum discards[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
    glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, 1, discards);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

And a couple of the helper methods just for completeness so you can follow it:

```
- (void)bufferTexCoordsForRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    AHTextureMap textureMaps[4] =
    {
        [self textureMapForPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect))
                          inRect:self.bounds],
        [self textureMapForPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect))
                          inRect:self.bounds],
        [self textureMapForPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect))
                          inRect:self.bounds],
        [self textureMapForPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect))
                          inRect:self.bounds]
    };

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(AHTextureMap), textureMaps, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}

- (AHTextureMap)textureMapForPoint:(CGPoint)point
                            inRect:(CGRect)outerRect
{
    CGPoint pt = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(point, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.contentScaleFactor, self.contentScaleFactor));

    return (AHTextureMap) { { pt.x, pt.y }, { point.x / outerRect.size.width, 1.0 - (point.y / outerRect.size.height) } };
}
```

Comment: > "and draw the back texture and scratch texture into my frame buffer"... how exactly are you doing this part?

Comment: I added a little code above to give some more context to how I'm drawing those framebuffers.  Feel free to take a look, and let me know what you think or if you have any questions!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are drawing each quad in a separate draw call.
If your stroke consist of a lot of quads(from sampling the bezier curve) your code will make many draw calls per frame.

Having many draw calls in OpenGL ES 2 on older iOS devices will probably generate a bottle neck on the CPU.
The reason is that draw calls in OpenGL ES 2 can have a lot of overhead in the driver.
The driver tries to organize the draw calls you make into something the GPU can digest and it does this organization using the CPU.

If you intend to draw many quads to simulate a brush stroke you should update a vertex buffer to contain many quads and then draw it with one draw call instead of making a draw call per quad.

You can verify that your bottle neck is in the CPU with the Time Profiler instrument.
You can then check if the CPU is spending most of his time on the OpenGL draw call methods or rather on your own functions.

If the CPU spends most of it's time on the OpenGL draw call methods it is likely because you are making too many draw calls per frame.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response, but that's not really what's happening.  None of the code above is showing any of the actual drawing code which takes input touch points and turns it into bezier curves, and then vertices from bezier curves.  I've tested all of that code pretty extensively using the timer tool and the OpenGL tool, and that doesn't appear to be the bottleneck.  The bottleneck is definitely somewhere in the texture rendering.

Comment: "Texture rendering"? Do you mean render target? If your rendering is bellow the target FPS the xcode OpenGL frame Analyzer will usually tell you what is your bottle neck. Try to grab an OpenGL snapshot while you swipe your finger and see if you are bellow the render target?

Comment: You do know you can see how much CPU/GPU you make use of(even how much tiler you use) live by clicking the FPS meter?

Comment: Thanks again! Yeah I do know how to use the CPU/GPU meters for live debugging, and I use that a good bit.  Can you tell me a bit more about Xcode frame analyzer telling me where the bottleneck is?  I've never seen that, only snapshots of a single frame.

As for the texture rendering part, what I mean is this:  the general process is 
1. Draw stroke to texture (by binding a texture-backed FBO)
2. Enable blending
3. Draw texture to main FBO (by binding to that FBO)

The bottleneck appears to be step 3.  Does that make sense? I'm relatively new at this so please correct if my vocabulary is wrong!

Comment: Yea, older device don't like when you use render targets(a texture you render into) as the resource of another shader. Which is what I think you are doing. A way around it might be double buffering. So step 3 takes the buffer of step 2 from the previous frame. I never actually witenessed a lot of performance boost this way but it might work. The Analyzer you tells you all sort of warnnings and errors when you select the FPS bar. Read everything it says.

Comment: The reason it doesn't like read after write textures is that it can't parallelize the work, when you read it, it has to wait until the write is finished. Double buffering might solve this, not sure.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you're saying to basically use a standard renderbuffer with a color attachment as opposed to a texture?  I tried that, but unless I'm missing something (which is entirely possible by the way), there's no way to copy from one renderbuffer into another in OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: You can use glFramebufferTexture2D to attach a render buffer with a color attachment to your texture. This way you can on one hand render into the texture and on the other hand use the texture for a shader sampler. Notice you cannot have the same framebuffer be both a render target and a shader sampler source in the same draw call. But it can play either part in separate draw calls. I don't think you too much, but you can "copy" render buffers by using a draw call with a simple shader that has one framebuffer's texture as a source and the other framebuffer as the render target.